# How to exclude wwwroot\lib in ASPNET Core using Visual Studio 2017

Tags: tfs, lib, wwwroot, libman

Using VSTS (not git) and use Visual Studio 2017 libman to manage client-side libraries.  These libraries are put in wwwroot\lib.  I don't want to add these to source code control.

I've tried putting a .tfignore in my project folder with:

```
wwwroot\lib
```

I also tried:

```
\wwwroot\lib
```

Regardless of what I do, all the wwwroot\lib files are put in source code control when I add a new client-side library via libman.

How can I ignore the lib files since they are managed/restored by Visual Studio libman feature?

Comment: Can you open an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/issues to dig into this deeper?

Comment: Submitted issue [#467](https://github.com/aspnet/LibraryManager/issues/467) via @Jimmy

Comment: `**/wwwroot/lib/` will probably work.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment above from [Seabizkit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262541/seabizkit), `**/wwwroot/lib` worked for me.